# Python create list and allow selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist, python-requests

I am totally new in python and having a headache trying to resolve the following..

I am building a code that goes into specific api website (https://test123.com), logs in by asking the user for username and password (so far so good), then using requests.get I am able to get some groupIDs and descriptions, then it cleans all additional characters ending up with a file that has X number of lines where odd lines contains the database groupID and the even lines the description (example:

6329b6f7b5

East Coast

635c04e2af6d9f1

West Coast
...

The problem comes when I am trying to make this a list or menu displaying the description only but at the backend tied it up with the groupID so the user can select as many as needed and when done pass only the groupIDs of the selection to the next task since my next api command only uses the groupID, but to make it friendly for the user I must show the description. I've been looking everywhere and I can't get it to work and always get back to the beggining. So far I have this:

```
f = open("cgIDmod2.txt", "r")
list = []
for line in f:
    list.append(line)
print (list)
f.close()
```

Please help me as much as possible. Thanks for your time and cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what exactly you're asking for in the second part.

If you just need to read the lines from your output file into a list then you could do this:

```
with open("cgIDmod2.txt") as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
```

Output:

```
['6329b6f7b5', 'East Coast', '635c04e2af6d9f1', 'West Coast']
```

If you wanted only the descriptions you could do:

```
with open("cgIDmod2.txt") as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file][1::2]
```

Output:

```
['East Coast', 'West Coast']
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
with open("cgIDmod2.txt") as file:
    values = {code.strip():zone.strip() for code,zone in zip(file,file)}
```

Output:

```
{'6329b6f7b5': 'East Coast', '635c04e2af6d9f1': 'West Coast'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!.. So for the second part, I would like to create variables for each line maybe and allow the user to select east coast & central for example, maybe something like a list where the user can select option 1 and option 3 and save that answer.. once I have that answer I can equal that to the variable containing the groupID... the flow I am trying to get is the user select all zones as needed, then in the backend (code) it will convert any picked zone into their own unique ID, because my following task will send a webapi query to collect data from those groupIDs.

Comment: Ah, I don't think a list is the best option for you then. It sounds like you plan on trying to match up the 2 lists to convert a zone to a unique ID?

If so you'd probably be better off with a dictionary where the key/value pairs are the unique IDs and zones

Comment: is there a way you can please help me with the dictionary? I even try the menu and I failed..

Comment: Added dictionary to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact output, I think that you can work with 2 separated arrays (assuming that all data from the txt file is organised in alternate lines) like in the code below, but rather than printing the data, you can get all the indexes of the wanted descriptions from user, and then return the groupsID using those indexes, or gather other data with the groupsID:

```
file_path = 'cgIDmod2.txt'

group_ids = []
descriptions = []

# So here the cgIDmod2.txt file is been read
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    # Deal with alternate lines
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        # remove the whitespaces
        group_id = lines[i].strip()
        description = lines[i + 1].strip()
        # Add them in the two arrays
        group_ids.append(group_id)
        descriptions.append(description)

# For the data (group_ids and descriptions), they are related by index, and you can use them individually or in relation with both
for i in range(len(group_ids)):
    print(f"Group ID: {group_ids[i]}, Description: {descriptions[i]}")
```

Additionally, you can use `dictionay` (hashmap) to relate the two data(group_ids/) as key/value:

```
file_path = 'cgIDmod2.txt'

data_dict = {}

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        group_id = lines[i].strip()
        description = lines[i + 1].strip()
        # the key in this case is group_id (the index) and the value is description
        data_dict[group_id] = description
        # You can do this also: data_dict[description] = group_id

for group_id in data_dict:
    print(f"Group ID: {group_id}, Description: {data_dict[group_id]}")
    # print(f"Group ID: {data_dict[description]}, Description: {description}")
```

Print:

```
Group ID: 6329b6f7b5, Description: East Coast
Group ID: 635c04e2af6d9f1, Description: West Coast
```

Comment: Please excuse my delayed answer. I had to deal with personal matters. I will try your solution and give you feedback. I do really appreciate the effort, time and help!

Comment: No problem, Great to hear that the solution helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind one more question, but I am trying now to ask the user how many groups will the user require, then I am trying to use a while loop with <= answer to generate x number of questions ( Enter the groupID by copying and pasting or typing) but I want to ask as many times and the initial answer, let's say they typed 3, then I want to ask 3 times to enter 1 groupID at a time, then that answer save it as a variable (a1, a2, a3 a+1... so on.
So far I am trying this way but is not working:

gtotal = input("How many Groups will you require? \n")

g = [ ]

while g <= total:

```
g = input("Please copy and paste 1 group ID at a time then press Enter \n")
```

print(g)